# How to look up Oppidan and Ebenezer financial statements?

Tags: united-states, financial-statements

[Oppidan](https://oppidan.com/about/) is a property development firm with headquarters in Minnesota.  They partner with [Ebenezer](https://www.ebenezercares.org/about-us) to run senior care facilities.  I would like to know more about the finances of these two companies.  I can't even tell if they're private or public.  Thus, I'd assume private?  Do large private companies report earnings?  How do I find any official financial statements?

[This random website](https://www.globaldata.com/store/report/oppidan-ebenezer-chaska-road-senior-housing-complex-minnesota/) claims Oppidan and Ebenezer are wholly-owned subsidiaries of Fairview Hospital.  That seems unlikely to me, but how do I verify whether it's true?

P.S.  [This Fairview Hospital financial statement](https://emma.msrb.org/P11592185-P11228601-.pdf) says Fairview operates "senior care housing and long-term care facilities", so it could be related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Financial statements**

I tried to look up these companies on [EDGAR](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html), but could not find them, so it is safe to assume that they are not publicly traded on a US stock exchange. Next, I used the Minnesota Secretary of State's [business filings search tool](https://mblsportal.sos.state.mn.us/Business/Search), and found some information:

- [Oppidan Investment Company](https://mblsportal.sos.state.mn.us/Business/SearchDetails?filingGuid=3796937b-b1d4-e011-a886-001ec94ffe7f) — This is a privately held business corporation. Private corporations generally do not make their financial statements publicly available.
- [Ebenezer Society](https://mblsportal.sos.state.mn.us/Business/SearchDetails?filingGuid=20266451-b7d4-e011-a886-001ec94ffe7f) — This is a nonprofit corporation. Its Form 990 "Return of Organization Exempt from Income Tax" filings can be found using the IRS' [Tax Exempt Organization Search tool](https://www.irs.gov/charities-non-profits/search-for-tax-exempt-organizations). Here is its [2019 Form 990 filing](https://apps.irs.gov/pub/epostcard/cor/410706141_201912_990_2021021917730341.pdf) containing information about its revenues, expenses, assets, and liabilities. The filings for 2020 and 2021 are missing, probably because of IRS backlog:

  > Data Updates Delayed
  >
  > Expect delays in data updates for the Tax Exempt Organization Search tool. We are still processing paper-filed 990 series received 2021 and later.

**Relationship between Fairview and Ebenezer**

According to Part III of Ebenezer's Form 990 filing:

> WITH OUR PARTNERS AT FAIRVIEW HEALTH SERVICES, WE PROVIDE ACCESS THROUGHOUT MINNESOTA TO A FULL RANGE OF HOUSING OPTIONS, COMMUNITY-BASED PROGRAMS AND SERVICES.

According to [Ebenezer's website](https://www.ebenezercares.org):

> Through our partnership with Fairview, Ebenezer is ​able to offer Hospice and Palliative Care as well as Care at Home.

According to [Fairview Health Services' website](https://www.fairview.org/Resources):

> Ebenezer is Minnesota’s largest provider of senior care. Our partnership with Ebenezer allows us to expand our expertise and services even further ...

It appears that both nonprofits have an agreement to cooperate.

Comment: Great answer. I wish I could give it five upvotes.